# How can I fill an array with sets

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, set

Say I have an image of `2x2` pixels named `image_array`, each pixel color is identified by a tuple of 3 entries (RGB), so the shape of `image_array` is `2x2x3`.

I want to create an np.array `c` which has the shape `2x2x1` and which last coordinate is an empty set.

I tried this:

```
import numpy as np
image = (((1,2,3), (1,0,0)), ((1,1,1), (2,1,2)))
image_array = np.array(image)

c = np.empty(image_array.shape[:2], dtype=set)
c.fill(set())
c[0][1].add(124)
print(c)
```

I get:

```
[[{124} {124}]
 [{124} {124}]]
```

And instead I would like the return:

```
[[{} {124}]
 [{} {}]]
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Do you mean that each element of your `c` should be a `set`?

Comment: yes that's what I mean.

Comment: Very much related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly

Comment: `dtype=set` is really the same as `dtype=object`.  So items, including sets, are stored in the same way as in lists - by reference.

Comment: the point @cs95 made is what i explained in my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object array has to be filled with separate `set()` objects.  That means creating them individually, as I do with a list comprehension:

```
In [279]: arr = np.array([set() for _ in range(4)]).reshape(2,2)                                     
In [280]: arr                                                                                        
Out[280]: 
array([[set(), set()],
       [set(), set()]], dtype=object)
```

That construction should highlight that fact that this array is closely related to a list, or list of lists.

Now we can do a set operation on one of those elements:

```
In [281]: arr[0,1].add(124)     # more idiomatic than arr[0][1]                                                                          
In [282]: arr                                                                                        
Out[282]: 
array([[set(), {124}],
       [set(), set()]], dtype=object)
```

Note that we cannot operate on more than one set at a time. The object array offers few advantages compared to a list.

This is a 2d array; the sets don't form a dimension.  Contrast that with

```
In [283]: image = (((1,2,3), (1,0,0)), ((1,1,1), (2,1,2))) 
     ...: image_array = np.array(image) 
     ...:                                                                                            
In [284]: image_array                                                                                
Out[284]: 
array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [1, 0, 0]],

       [[1, 1, 1],
        [2, 1, 2]]])
```

While it started with tuples, it made a 3d array of integers.

Answer (score 1):

whenever you do `fill(set())`, this will fill the array with *exactly* same set, as they refer to the same set. To fix this, just make a set if there isnt one everytime you need to add to the set

```
c = np.empty(image_array.shape[:2], dtype=set)
if not c[0][1]:
    c[0,1] = set([124])
else:
    c[0,1].add(124)
print (c)

# [[None {124}]
#  [None None]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.empty((2, 2), dtype=np.object)
x[0, 0] = set(1, 2, 3)

print(x)
[[{1, 2, 3} None]
 [None None]]
```

For non-number types in numpy you should use `np.object`.

Comment: i think he wants his array to have sets of integers for some reason, though

Comment: ok thanks, the problem came from `c[0][1]`. If I replace it by `c[0,1]` it works. Thanks

Comment: Using `empty` when you intend to only set one element usually isn't a good idea.  But with `object` dtype, `empty` fills with `None`.  As part of your answer you should show the resulting `x`.

Answer (score -2):

Try changing your line `c[0][1].add` to this.

```py
c[0][1] = 124
print(c)
```